# Ajax listener and Converter on multiple fields - new value not passed to listener

Tags: ajax, jsf, converters

I need to update 'pickupdate' based on the value selected in 'pickuphour'.

My problem is that when the update listener is called, the newly selected 'pickuphour' value is not available in the listener method.

It appears the listener is called before the converter updates my bean 'pickuptime' value.

(I used the DatePartConverter here:[Binding more than one input field to a backing bean property by using Java Server Faces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930567/binding-more-than-one-input-field-to-a-backing-bean-property-by-using-java-serve))

How do I get the newly selected hour value before or while in the listener method?

```
<h:panelGroup>
                <h:form id="pickuptime">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="pickupdate" widgetVar="pickupdate" value="#{journeyCRUD.pickuptime}" immediate="true"> 
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Today" itemValue="#{journeyCRUD.dateList[0]}" noSelectionOption="true"/>  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tomorrow" itemValue="#{journeyCRUD.dateList[1]}" /> 
                            <f:selectItems value="#{util:subList(journeyCRUD.dateList, 2, 30)}" var="date" itemValue="#{date}" itemLabel="#{util:formatDate(date, 'EEE dd MMM yyyy','EEE dd MMM')}"/>
                            <f:converter converterId="datePartConverter"/>
                            <f:attribute name="part" value="date"/>
                            <f:ajax execute="@this pickuphour pickupmin"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu> 
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="pickuphour" widgetVar="pickuphour" value="#{journeyCRUD.pickuptime}" immediate="true" >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{journeyCRUD.hourList}"/> 
                            <f:converter converterId="datePartConverter"/>
                            <f:attribute name="part" value="hour"/>
                            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{journeyCRUD.updatePickupDate}" execute="@this pickupmin"  render="pickupdate" immediate="true"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu> 
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="pickupmin" widgetVar="pickupmin" value="#{journeyCRUD.pickuptime}" immediate="true">  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{journeyCRUD.minuteList}"/> 
                            <f:converter converterId="datePartConverter"/>
                            <f:attribute name="part" value="minutes"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu> 
                    </h:form>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

This converter only returns the updated model value after all values have been set. If you want to keep using this converter, your best bet is to extract it straight from the component which is available by `<f:ajax listener>` argument.

```
public updatePickupDate(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    UIInput component = (UIInput) event.getComponent();
    Object value = Component.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: tried it but 'value' is still the previously selected value rather than the new value.